# x:Bind and nested class in a UWP application

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp

I am currently working on a UWP application and I would like to use the compiled binding system.

I have a base that extends the `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page` that contains a property `ViewModel`.

Here the base class of the `ViewModel` Property :

```
 public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaiseOnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
      OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
      if (PropertyChanged != null)
      {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
      }
    }

  }
```

And here my base page :

```
public abstract class BasePage : Page
{

  public BaseViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

}
```

The pages of my app extends the `BasePage` and contain a nester (inner) class that extends the `BaseViewModel` class. Here a sample code :

```
public sealed partial class MyPage : BasePage
{

  public sealed class MyViewModel : BaseViewModel
  {

      public string Title
      {
        get
        {
          return "Test";
        }
      }

    }

    public MyPage()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      ViewModel = MyViewModel();
    }
}
```

Now, I would like to bind the property `Title` of the `MyViewModel` class to my UI. According to [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt204783.aspx) and [this one](http://neilmosafi.blogspot.fr/2007/08/dec-06-wpfxaml-xtype-and-nested-classes.html), something like that should work :

```
<TextBlock 
  Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.(namespace:MyPage+MyViewModel.Title)}"  
/>
```

Unfortunately, I cannot compile. I have several errors on the generated file `MyPage.g.cs` due to the "+" char. Do you know if the binding on a nested (inner) class is supported in UWP application ? Perhaps it is supported only on WPF app ? :(

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Have you tried to simply write `{x:Bind ViewModel.Title}`?

Comment: @KooKiz : Yes I tried, but I have a compilation error. The property `Title` cannot be found for the type `BaseViewModel`. It is why I cast into `MyViewModel`. If I define my `MyViewModel` class in a separate file, the cast works fine. I only have the issue when the `MyViewModel` class is a nested class. So technically, I know the workaround, but I like nested classes so I would like to try with nested classes :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use a new property in order to avoid the cast and the nested class access into the XAML file. So the solution is to use something like :

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : BasePage
{

  public sealed class MyViewModel : BaseViewModel
  {
    public string Title
    {
      get
      {
        return "Test";
      }
    }
  }

  public MyViewModel LocalViewModel
  {
    get
    {
      return (MyViewModel) ViewModel;
    }
  }

  public MainPage()
  {
    this.InitializeComponent();
    ViewModel = new MyViewModel();
  }
}
```

So, using the `x:Bind` syntax, the XAML looks like :

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind LocalViewModel.Title}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some problem while casting with "+" char in `{x:Bind}`. While using `{x:Bind ViewModel.(local:MyPage+MyViewModel.Title)}` in *MyPage.xaml*, it generates code like following in *MyPage.g.cs* to update bound data:

```
private void Update_ViewModel(global::UWP.BaseViewModel obj, int phase)
{
    if (obj != null)
    {
        if ((phase & (NOT_PHASED | (1 << 0))) != 0)
        {
            this.Update_ViewModel__local_MyPage+MyViewModel_Title_(((global::UWP.MyPage.MyViewModel)(obj)).Title, phase);
        }
    }
}
private void Update_ViewModel__local_MyPage+MyViewModel_Title_(global::System.String obj, int phase)
{
    if((phase & ((1 << 0) | NOT_PHASED )) != 0)
    {
        XamlBindingSetters.Set_Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_TextBlock_Text(this.obj2, obj, null);
    }
}
```

Although the cast generated is right, but the method name `Update_ViewModel__local_MyPage+MyViewModel_Title_` is invalid. So casting nested class in `{x:Bind}` is not supported by now.

If you want to use `{x:Bind}`, you can use `MyViewModel` instead of `BaseViewModel` as following, it will work well.

In the code-behind:

```
public sealed partial class MyPage : BasePage
{
    public MyViewModel myViewModel;

    public sealed class MyViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public string Title
        {
            get
            {
                return "Test";
            }
        }
    }

    public MyPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myViewModel = new MyViewModel();
    }
}
```

In the XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind myViewModel.Title}" />
```

Also, if you want to use `BaseViewModel`, you can use `{Binding}` instead of `{x:Bind}` since `{Binding}` uses general-purpose runtime object inspection.

In the code-behind:

```
public sealed partial class MyPage : BasePage
{
    public sealed class MyViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public string Title
        {
            get
            {
                return "Test";
            }
        }
    }

    public MyPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ViewModel = new MyViewModel();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

In the XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ViewModel.Title}" />
```