# UWP reflect CombBox selected item loaded from settings through binding

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, combobox, uwp

This is a continuation from [an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33821672/uwp-combobox-binding-to-selecteditem-property).

For some app settings I want to use a ComboBox to select an option. I can save the selected option to (roaming) settings and load it again. The loaded option is properly displayed in the TextBlock but the ComboBox shows a blank. How can I also reflect the loaded currently selected option in the ComboBox?

This is the XAML:

```
<Page
x:Class="ComboBoxTest.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:ComboBoxTest"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:converter="using:ComboBoxTest.Converter"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Page.Resources>
    <converter:ComboBoxItemConvert x:Key="ComboBoxItemConvert" />
</Page.Resources>


<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox 
            Name="ComboBox" 
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind ComboBoxOptions}" 
            SelectedItem="{x:Bind SelectedComboBoxOption, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ComboBoxItemConvert}}" 
            SelectedValuePath="ComboBoxOption" 
            DisplayMemberPath="ComboBoxHumanReadableOption"  
            Header="ComboBox" >
        </ComboBox>
        <TextBlock Name="BoundTextblock" Text="{x:Bind SelectedComboBoxOption.ComboBoxOption, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

And this is the code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace ComboBoxTest
{
/// <summary>
/// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
/// </summary>
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ApplicationDataContainer roamingSettings = null;

    private ObservableCollection<ComboBoxItem> ComboBoxOptions;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        ComboBoxOptions = new ObservableCollection<ComboBoxItem>();
        ComboBoxOptionsManager.GetComboBoxList(ComboBoxOptions);


        roamingSettings = ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings;


        var value = (string)roamingSettings.Values["ComboBoxSelection"];
        if (value != null)
        {
            SelectedComboBoxOption = Deserialize<ComboBoxItem>(value); //loaded selection reflected in the textbox but not in the ComboBox
        }
        else
        {
            SelectedComboBoxOption = ComboBoxOptions[0];
        }

    }

    public class ComboBoxItem
    {
        public string ComboBoxOption { get; set; }
        public string ComboBoxHumanReadableOption { get; set; }
    }

    public class ComboBoxOptionsManager
    {
        public static void GetComboBoxList(ObservableCollection<ComboBoxItem> ComboBoxItems)
        {
            var allItems = getComboBoxItems();
            ComboBoxItems.Clear();
            allItems.ForEach(p => ComboBoxItems.Add(p));
        }

        private static List<ComboBoxItem> getComboBoxItems()
        {
            var items = new List<ComboBoxItem>();

            items.Add(new ComboBoxItem() { ComboBoxOption = "Option1", ComboBoxHumanReadableOption = "Option 1" });
            items.Add(new ComboBoxItem() { ComboBoxOption = "Option2", ComboBoxHumanReadableOption = "Option 2" });
            items.Add(new ComboBoxItem() { ComboBoxOption = "Option3", ComboBoxHumanReadableOption = "Option 3" });

            return items;
        }
    }

    private ComboBoxItem _SelectedComboBoxOption;

    public ComboBoxItem SelectedComboBoxOption
    {
        get
        {
            return _SelectedComboBoxOption;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_SelectedComboBoxOption != value)
            {
                _SelectedComboBoxOption = value;
                roamingSettings.Values["ComboBoxSelection"] = Serialize(value);
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedComboBoxOption");
            }
        }
    }




    public static string Serialize(object obj)
    {
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
            serializer.Serialize(sw, obj);
            return sw.ToString();
        }
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(string xml)
    {
        using (var sw = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            return (T)serializer.Deserialize(sw);
        }
    }


    void RaisePropertyChanged(string prop)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) { PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop)); }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This a typical case of items that look the same, but aren't since they have different references (read on [C# reference types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx)).

You load the `ComboBox` with 3 values and these 3 values are shown in the dropdown. To see a selected item when the `ComboBox` is closed, it has to be (= have the same reference as) one of these 3 values. When you have nothing saved in your roaming settings, you then select the first one as `SelectedItem`. Switching to another selected item, you will also have a valid reference in the `SelectedItem` property.

However when you deserialize the saved `RoamingSettings` value, you create a new object with a different reference. When you set this item as the `SelectedItem`, the `ComboBox` control will not find it in its items and thus not select an item.

To fix this, you'll have to find the correct item in the `ItemSource` collection:

```
var value = (string)roamingSettings.Values["ComboBoxSelection"];
if (value != null)
{
    var deserialized = Deserialize<ComboBoxItem>(value);
    // using ComboBoxOption as the primary key field of your object
    SelectedComboBoxOption = ComboBoxOptions.SingleOrDefault(c => 
                c.ComboBoxOption == deserialized.ComboBoxOption);
}
else
{
    SelectedComboBoxOption = ComboBoxOptions[0];
}
```